# Remove comma after title ending with questionmark

Tags: bibtex, punctuation

I am using a bit modified bibtex style but with quite common base. It is based on utphys 2.7 which is based on "IEEE Transactions bibliography style (29-Jan-88 version)"

I'd like to remove comma after titles ending with question marks. Some automated hack will do. (Not changing the bbl)

Bibtex entery is as follows:

```
@article{EPR35,
 author = {Einstein, A. and Podolsky, B. and Rosen, N.},
 title = {Can Quantum-Mechanical Description of Physical Reality Be Considered Complete?}
}
```

And corresponding output is like:

> A. Einstein, B. Podolsky ja N. Rosen, “Can quantum-mechanical description of physical
>   reality be considered complete?,” Phys. Rev. 47 (May, 1935) 777–780. 5, 8

Bibtex style is at http://pastebin.com/h8in9BZU

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `makebst` package has a nice function to test whether the last character of a string is one of `! ? .":

```
FUNCTION {non.stop}
{ duplicate$
   "}" * add.period$
   #-1 #1 substring$ "." =
}
```

Then you can write an `add.comma` function that tests that:

```
FUNCTION {add.comma}
{ non.stop
    { "," * }
    'skip$
  if$
}
```

Use this `add.comma` function in places where you want the conditional comma.

Comment: +1 Nice. I was playing with using `add.period$` as a base for my function, but couldn't get it working in all cases. It's obvious now that I see how to do it!

Answer (score 7):

I think on solution could be to redefine the question marks local by setting:

```
\catcode`?=\active
```

To provide a mwe I saved your linked bst-file with the name `utphys.bst`. You should avoid spaces or other special characters inside your filename. (I think a dot is also wrong)

In the example below I defined a new if-function to which will be true after a question mark. If this function is true no comma will be printed.

The result without the redefinition:

[image]

The result with the modification:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@article{EPR35,
 author = {Einstein, A. and Podolsky, B. and Rosen, N.},
 title = {Can Quantum-Mechanical Description of Physical Reality Be Considered Complete?}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\cite{EPR35}


\begingroup
\newif\ifgobblecomma
\gobblecommafalse %default
\edef\FZ{?}
\edef\KM{,}
\catcode`?=\active
\catcode`,=\active
\def?{\FZ\gobblecommatrue}
\def,{\ifgobblecomma\gobblecommafalse\else\KM\fi}
\bibliographystyle{utphys}
\bibliography{references}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm also using a modified `utphys.sty` style. A quick hack that I use to remove the extra commas in the titles is to define the following function in the style file:

```
INTEGERS{steps}
FUNCTION {add.comma$}
{   
    #-1 'steps :=
    {duplicate$ steps #1 substring$ "}" =}
        {steps #1 - 'steps := }
    while$
    duplicate$ steps #1 substring$ "?" =
        {"" *}  % string ended in ? so don't do anything skip$
        {"," *} % string didn't end in ? so add a comma
    if$
}
```

Then, the only change to the `format.title` function is to insert a call to `add.comma$`

```
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title empty$
    { "" }
    {"``" title "t" change.case$ * add.comma$ "''" * }
  if$
}
```

This is good enough for my bibliography, however the `add.comma$` function only does the bare minimum it that it needs in order to work *in my case*. It should probably be made more robust so that it works with whitespace and punctuation other than "?".