# Comma after article title with biblatex-chicago and xelatex

Tags: biblatex, punctuation, biblatex-chicago

This has been asked a few times before, but according to the `biblatex-chicago` manual on page 178, this was supposed to be fixed in 1.0rc5 in Jan 2018 (at least for subtitles of books).

My problem is that I still get a comma after a question mark in both an `incollection` and `article` type.

I saw [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56563/remove-comma-after-title-ending-with-questionmark) which might work, but I am hoping that perhaps there is something that is wrong with how I am loading `biblatex-chicago` that I can easily fix.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=us]{english}
\usepackage[english=american]{csquotes} 

\usepackage[noibid,backend=biber,notes,isbn=false,shorthandfull,shorthandfirst,inheritshorthand=true,citereset=chapter,longcrossref=bib]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{temp.bib}
    @collection{bigbook,
        editor = {John Q. Editormann},
        title  = {A Collection of Essays},
        publisher = {Oxford University Press},
        address = {Oxford},
        year = {1995}}
    @incollection{incol,
        crossref = {bigbook},
        author   = {Steve Authormann},
        title    = {Where is the Comma?},
        pages    = {1-15}}
    @article{art1,
        author   = {Mark Articlemann},
        title    = {Is there a Comma?},
        journal  = {Journal of Grammar Questions},
        volume   = {2},
        issue    = {3},
        year     = {1995},
        pages    = {16-30}}
    \end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{temp.bib}

\begin{document}
I need to reference this in a footnote.\footcite[12]{incol} But this is
another footnote.\footcite[18]{art1}
\clearpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And here is what the footnotes look like:

[image: Footnotes]

The commas should not be there after the question mark in the titles. What is the best way to remove them?

I went ahead and showed all the options I am currently using for `biblatex-chicago` even though they aren't necessary for this MWE.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `\DeclarePunctuationPairs{<identifier>}{<characters>}` you can tell `biblatex` after which `<characters>` the punctuation `<identifier>` is allowed. After all other punctuation `<identifier>` is suppressed. (Of course this only works properly if all punctuation marks are typeset with `biblatex`'s punctuation commands. But that is the case in `biblatex-chicago` and other well-written `biblatex` styles.)

The default `biblatex` settings for the comma are

```
\DeclarePunctuationPairs{comma}{*!?}
```

which allows the comma after a an abbreviation dot, and after exclamation and question marks.

The `american` localisation modules issues `\uspunctuation`, which sets

```
\DeclarePunctuationPairs{comma}{*}
```

allowing a comma only after abbreviation dots and suppressing it in all other contexts.

But then `biblatex-chicago` explicitly overrides this decision (e.g. in `chicago-notes.cbx`, 2020/04/20 v 3.14)

```
% American-specific punctuation change for 16th edition %

\DefineBibliographyExtras{american}{%
  \DeclarePunctuationPairs{comma}{*!?}}
```

and allows commas after "!" and "?" again.

You can override this as follows

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=us]{english}
\usepackage[english=american]{csquotes} 

\usepackage[backend=biber,notes,
  noibid,
%  citereset=chapter,
  shorthandfull,shorthandfirst,inheritshorthand=true,
  longcrossref=bib,
  isbn=false,
]{biblatex-chicago}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{american}{\DeclarePunctuationPairs{comma}{*}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@collection{bigbook,
  editor    = {John Q. Editormann},
  title     = {A Collection of Essays},
  publisher = {Oxford University Press},
  address   = {Oxford},
  year      = {1995},
}
@incollection{incol,
  crossref = {bigbook},
  author   = {Steve Authormann},
  title    = {Where is the Comma?},
  pages    = {1-15},
}
@article{art1,
  author   = {Mark Articlemann},
  title    = {Is there a Comma?},
  journal  = {Journal of Grammar Questions},
  volume   = {2},
  issue    = {3},
  year     = {1995},
  pages    = {16-30},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
I need to reference this in a footnote.\footcite[12]{incol} But this is
another footnote.\footcite[18]{art1}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Steve Authormann, “Where is the Comma?” In A Collection of Essays, ed. John Q. Editormann (Oxford: Oxford University Press, 1995), 12.//Mark Articlemann, “Is there a Comma?” Journal of Grammar Questions 2 (3 1995): 18.]

Comment: Moewe to the rescue, again! Thanks so much, I hadn't looked to see that it was overridden. This works perfectly.